# Matchbox_Keyboard_FONT_SIZE

Tags: display

I have matchbox keyboard installed on PI-2 with TFT 5 inch screen. It appears the keys should be able to support a LARGER font size. Can this be done and how.

Comment: Have you made any research at all? Please add your findings!

Comment: Yes I have searched prior to going to RPI stackexchange with nothing helpful.

Comment: To be extra clear, I am looking to get Matchbox individual keys to show the the letter/character/number in LARGER font size with minimum wasted white space borders.The characters generated in terminal are fully readable, however the keys on 5" TFT screen are almost unreadable for senior eyes.